# Does gmail still ignore DKIM if SPF passes, DMARC style?

Tags: gmail, spf, dkim, dmarc

This blog post from 2016 shockingly implies that gmail will accept an email if [***either*** SPF or DKIM passes](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2016/08/making-email-safer-with-new-security-warnings-in-gmail.html).  We use G suite SMTP servers, therefore SPF provides almost *zero* protection from spoofing. Is this still the case?

[Since DMARC only needs one policy to succeed](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/171387/dmarc-policy-result-when-exactly-one-of-spf-and-dkim-fails-and-exactly-one-succe), would implementing DMARC with SPF+DKIM guarantee the security issue?

Comment: for succinctness: the answer is yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That article mentions a new "security warning" in which:

> On the web or Android, if you receive a message that can’t be authenticated with either Sender Policy Framework (SPF) or DKIM, you’ll see a question mark in place of the sender’s profile photo, corporate logo, or avatar.
>
> [image: screen shot of link in question]

This has nothing to do with accepting a message for delivery. All it means is that, when **neither** DKIM nor SPF pass (presumably with [alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC#Alignment)), the image used to represent the sender will be replaced by that gray stop-sign with a bold red question mark on it, as demonstrated in the screen shot.

This was an early attempt at something like [BIMI](https://bimigroup.org/) (though in the other direction; this is an image to warn of potential spoofing rather than an image that is robust against spoofing) and I think it's a good protective step.

As of 2016, [Google and many others block mail when DMARC invokes its reject policy](https://dmarc.org/2016/02/how-can-i-tell-who-is-using-dmarc/), so this only affects senders that do not use [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) `p=reject` (which can only trigger when neither SPF nor DKIM passes with alignment).

Back before DMARC, SPF was widely deployed and its use of `-all` and `~all` had very low efficacy; blocking based on either would result in blocking vast volumes of legitimate mail. The SpamAssassin community even concluded that `~all` (soft fail) was a stronger spam indicator than `-all` (hard fail)!

Without DMARC, senders don't see when their mail fails to properly verify with DKIM or SPF (barring [RFC 6652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6652), which I've never seen used). They therefore cannot determine if their failure condition (spf `-all`) works (and DKIM doesn't a failure condition) and neither has a suggested failure *policy*. DMARC provides the reporting mechanism to determine what issues may arise with a blocking policy and then lets senders issue such a policy.

If you want to *require* DKIM, I suggest an SPF record of `v=spf1 ?all` so that SPF can never pass (nor can it ever fail). Then your DMARC `p=reject` can deny any mail purportedly from your domain unless it passes DKIM. At that point, SPF isn't necessary (DKIM is really hard to replay and basically impossible to forge).

Comment: I consider showing a "gray stop-sign with a bold red question mark on it" to be non-acceptance.  So spoofing was what I was referring to in my question.

Comment: When I hear "acceptance", I'm thinking "delivery". Messages that fail _both_ SPF and DKIM either fail DMARC and are **blocked** by `p=reject` or else are given these warning icons. _Either_ SPF or DKIM will prevent _both_ DMARC rejection _and_ this warning icon.

Comment: I have updated my answer to better relate how necessary DMARC reporting is to setting a usable rejection policy. If GMail sees a DMARC `p=reject`, the message will not be delivered. That is strong security.